# Js txt file reading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, file

Have php code which writes some data in .txt files

```
<?php $f = fopen("bot-name.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($f, $_POST["botname"]);  
fclose($f);
$g = fopen("secret-code.txt", "w"); 
fwrite($g, $_POST["code"]);  
fclose($g); 
?>
```

And js script which read this files

```
function() {
    // Выполняем периодические действия
  $('#bot_nick').load('http://totobank.ru/extension/bot-name.txt');
  $('#bot_secret').load('http://totobank.ru/extension/secret-code.txt');

    setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);
}
```

This doesn't work, what i did wrong?

Comment: What does "this doesn't work" mean? Errors in console? Errors in PHP?

Comment: something wrong with js script i think

Comment: No help at all. What is the `setTimeout(arguments.callee, 2000);` supposed to do?

Comment: did u check text documents..?

Comment: Please put your complete code in here....

Comment: Please post the code that posts the data and calls the function

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, @hype. Please describe the exact symptoms you're getting. For example, was the file created, but it's empty? Was the data written incorrectly? Did you receive any error messages? The more complete the information you give, the better the chances that someone will be able to help you.

Answer (score -1):

```js
var api = "http://totobank.ru/extension/bot-name.txt";
var wait = false;

function sayBotName() {
  if(wait) return;
  wait = true;
  
  var r = new XMLHttpRequest();
  r.addEventListener("load", function(d) {
    // that's all!
    wait = false;
  });
  r.open("GET", api);
  r.send();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="sayBotName()" id="foo">tell me the bot name</button>
```

Comment: Why use xmlhttprequest when you have jQuery? Also where is the description of what you did? It seems I would have to click again and again to get the file?

Comment: the availability of jQuery doesn't seem granted... It's is dependencies-free!
By the way, that script explains you how to load a file via javascript over an http request...

Comment: $('#bot_nick').load is jQuery Ajax

Comment: the load api doesn't read (as asked in the title) but places a content (from url) in an element... by the way, you don't need ajQuery in that case...

Comment: Op believes the load part is the problem. Why are we discussing this?

Comment: If he wants read a remote file (as He asked in the question), my answer does that...